# Use Progressbar in a separate thread in order to run simultaneously in two different tasks

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I want to run two functions simultaneously.

The first function will count the total number of files in my computer and will show the result in one DatagridView.

And in the second function, one progress bar's value will be changed according to the total number of files, meaning that when all files are bound in the DatagridView, the progress bar's value will be set to 100.

I want to synchronize the two functions' work, I am using two threads but the result does not show, an exception occurred.

What should I do ?

my code is

```
 ThreadStart threadstatr = new ThreadStart(Function_1);
 ThreadStart threaProgress = new ThreadStart(Function_2);
 Thread thread = new Thread(threadstatr);
 Thread threadpro = new Thread(threaProgress);
 thread.Start();
 threadpro.Start();
 thread.Join();
 threadpro.Join();

void Function_2()
    {
        int coun = ((Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text)) / 100); //here label1 represents total no. of files
        for (int i = 0; i < coun; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
```

and exception is "Input string was not in a correct format." as the label does not get chance to update itself

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code? Why do you have a separate thread for the progress bar anyway?

Comment: as above, and, what was the exception?

Comment: ThreadStart threadstatr = new ThreadStart(Function_1);
ThreadStart threaProgress = new ThreadStart(Function_2);
 Thread thread = new Thread(threadstatr);
 Thread threadpro = new Thread(threaProgress);
   thread.Start();
     threadpro.Start();
       thread.Join();
         threadpro.Join();

Comment: @AnimeshDatta it's better if you edit your question to include the code, rather than adding it to a comment.

Comment: A count is singular so why would you show it in a DatagridView?  Look at BackGroundWorker with ReportsProgress for the list of files.

Comment: In the second function i try to update the progress bar by this code                                                                { int count = ((Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text)) / 100);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }} here label1 is number of files in my computer and exception is " Input string was not in a correct format" as the label1 does not get updated  , what i have to do ?

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format.", so clearly label1.text isn't a number.

Comment: Those variable names make me want to hurt myself...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm its seems a little more complicated than it needs to be.  Using BackgroundWorker should enable you to avoid raw Thread objects (ThreadStart etc) completely.

You have a Main app / UI thread where your progress bar is instantiated.
You want to use a `BackgroundWorker` to spin up a thread to do the work - by hooking up your work (search files) method to the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event.
That method can report progress back to the UI thread using `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method.
Your UI thread can react to progress (increment progress control) by handling `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event.
Dont forget to set `BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true` when you create your BackgroundWorker.

You can get loads more detail on this by looking at doc for BackgoundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Not to repeat another answer and my comment but you don't seem to be listening.

Drop the threads.  No ThreadStart in your code.

And don't read a UI control from a the background.
Pass data:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(numberToCompute);
```

Use BackgroundWorker.

This does exactly what you need if you will follow.

[BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)